# Inserting multiple rows into table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

So I basically have 2 arrays with a lot of numbers in them, I implode them:

```
 $array1 = implode(", ", $array1);
 $array2 = implode(", ", $array2);
```

When I echo $array1 and $array2 it looks okay, numbers separated by commas

But when I use:

```
 "INSERT INTO table1 (array1, array2) VALUES ('$array1', '$array2')";
```

It only inserts first number (which is the first row in the csv file), what should I do now?

Comment: Presumably, the code is not sitting in a loop that is reading from each row of the input file.  I think you should edit the question to better describe what you are trying to accomplish.  What does the file look like, for example?

Comment: It's a CSV file with 2 columns and 100+ rows, array1 and array2 represent the columns, all the rows are in there separated by commas

Comment: What is `implode.(..`? Is that something new or is it a typo (I mean with the '.' between implode and `(`)

Comment: @putvande typo, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution in it's most basic form

```
$array1 = Array(1,2,3,4,5);
$array2 = Array("one","two","three","four","five");

while(count($array1)>0){
    $a1 = array_shift($array1);
    $b1 = array_shift($array2);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (numeric,alpha) VALUES('$a1','$b1')");
}
```